# Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was told to work on the google api. 
its pretty much the same as FB but I am having a slight trouble with redirect_url

This is the url which my app is using to get a access token

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=**********3-uiqulutgsobu5df302tup49v6e6ae5qu.apps.googleusercontent.com?&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Default1.aspx&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=token
```

When I registered the app
I set the redirect_url to

```
http://localhost/Default1.aspx
```

In my project there is a page called Default.aspx. The name of the solution is Googleprofiles.

It gives me an error: 
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could

```
have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Default1.aspx
```

Looks very simple. But I am unable to fix it.. 
Need some expert help

Thanks
Sun

Comment: Does your local webserver have a Default1.aspx in its document root?

Comment: @Marc B: I am running it on my system. In my asp.net solution there is a Default1.aspx. In the namespace GoogleProfiles(which the name of the solution also)

Comment: Please add yout file structure

Answer (score 0):

Your `redirect_uri` is wrong, change it or rename your `Default.aspx` to `Default1.aspx`:

```
redirect_uri=http://localhost/Default.aspx
```

Comment: But whats the difference between having redirect_uri=http://localhost/Default.aspx and redirect_uri=http://localhost/Default1.aspx, If default1.aspx is in the solution. Anyways, I am trying it with the suggested uri

Comment: You said, "In my project there is a page called Default.aspx".

Comment: Sorry, In my project there is Default1.aspx under the solution GoogleProfiles. I have the redirect_url = http://localhost/Default1.aspx. I registered the app with Redirect URIs: http://localhost/Default1.aspx. I still gives me the same error resource cannot be found. Should I be having a port#